# how to define schema for nested arrays in Meteor?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am using SimpleSchema with Meteor for Structuring the Database Entries.

The problem is, I have an array of arrays and defined schema doesn't work.

here's a document example :

```
Courses.insert({  
   "persian_title":"persian title",
   "english_title":"english title",
   "free_for_all":true,
   "price":1000,
   "is_offer":false,
   "offer_price":500,
   "Seasons":[  
      {  
         "title":"first Season",
         "free_for_all":false,
         "Episodes":[  
            {  
               "title":"first Episode",
               "length":"12:10:00",
               "url":"test"
            },
            {  
               "title":"second Episode",
               "length":"0:10:00",
               "url":"test"
            },
            {  
               "title":"third Episode",
               "length":"14:10:00",
               "url":"test"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "title":"Second Season",
         "free_for_all":false,
         "Episodes":[  
            {  
               "title":"first Episode",
               "length":"12:10:00",
               "url":"test"
            },
            {  
               "title":"second Episode",
               "length":"0:10:00",
               "url":"test"
            },
            {  
               "title":"third Episode",
               "length":"14:10:00",
               "url":"test"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
})
```

and the Schema :

```
Courses = new Mongo.Collection("courses");
var Schemas = {};
Schemas.Courses = new SimpleSchema(
    {
        persian_title: {
            type: String
        },
        english_title: {
            type: String
        },
        free_for_all: {
            type: Boolean
        },

        price: {
            type: Number
        },
        is_offer: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        offer_price: {
            type: Number
        },


        // Seasons

        "Courses.$.Seasons": {
            type: [Object]
        },
        "Courses.$.Seasons.$.title": {
            type: String
        },
        "Courses.$.Seasons.$.free_for_all": {
            type: Boolean
        },
        // Episodes
        "Courses.$.Seasons.$.Episodes": {
            type: [Object]
        },
        "Courses.$.Seasons.$.Episodes.title": {
            type: String
        },
        "Courses.$.Seasons.$.Episodes.length": {
            type: String,
            max: 8
        },
        "Courses.$.Seasons.$.Episodes.url": {
            type: String,
            max: 1000
        }


    });
Courses.attachSchema(Schemas.Courses);
```

Simple Schema documention : https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#schema-keys

The question is how to define Schema for array of arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either explicitly define `Seasons.$.Episodes` in your schema with `type: [Object]`. Define the schema for the Seasons array of objects as follows:

```
Courses = new Mongo.Collection("courses");
var Schemas = {};
Schemas.Courses = new SimpleSchema(
    {
        persian_title: {
            type: String
        },
        english_title: {
            type: String
        },
        free_for_all: {
            type: Boolean
        },    
        price: {
            type: Number
        },
        is_offer: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        offer_price: {
            type: Number
        },    
        // Seasons
        "Seasons": {
            type: [Object]
        },
        "Seasons.$.title": {
            type: String
        },
        "Seasons.$.free_for_all": {
            type: Boolean
        },
        // Episodes
        "Seasons.$.Episodes": {
            type: [Object]
        },
        "Seasons.$.Episodes.$.title": {
            type: String
        },
        "Seasons.$.Episodes.$.length": {
            type: String,
            max: 8
        },
        "Seasons.$.Episodes.$.url": {
            type: String,
            max: 1000
        }
    });
Courses.attachSchema(Schemas.Courses);
```